# Sony VAIO Windows 7 keyboard goes into strange state on fumbled keystrokes

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sony-vaio

I am a bit of a fumble-fingered typist; I can hit several keys accidentally especially on
a long reach to the lower left (e.g, towards or including <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>FN</kbd>) or upper right (<kbd>BS</kbd>, <kbd>DELETE</kbd>, <kbd>HOME</kbd>, <kbd>END</kbd>, <kbd>NUMLK</kbd>).

Normally I just get a junk character, hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and go on with my life.

Once a day or so, when doing one of these long reaches on a Sony VAIO keyboard, that feels like a fumble,
the keyboard goes into strange state after which I cannot enter any standard printing characters.  When this happens, the underlying program seems to be getting odd characters when I push a regular key; I get beeps or some program action occurs.  Switching to another window with the mouse doesn't help. When I switch to a Firefox window, typing either <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> gets me a new Tab suggests that that the keyboard or the system thinks the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is depressed.

This make the machine effectively useless.

The "cure" is to log out an log back in again.  Problem goes away, but you lose all the running applications and any partially complete updates you may have made with them.  A PC that loses work you have done is pretty frustrating; they are supposed to be productivity enhancing, not productivity disabling devices.

It isn't the accessibility/sticky key options; I found them the first time this happened and turned them all off.

I've been living on Windows boxes and laptops since NT 3.5, and have never encountered this problem on any of those systems.  [I wouldn't buy a Sony again.]

Is there any way with just the mouse ask Windows or the VAIO what state the keyboard is in, just so I can verify its status?   Is there a way to reset the keyboard to decent state?   Is there something I can do to prevent this idiocy from occurring, other than becoming a perfect typist?

Comment: I beginning to suspect I have a "Windows key magically stuck on" problem; see http://superuser.com/a/660989/8986.  I have to wait for my next event.

Comment: Digging across the internet, it appears that NumLk "happens by accident" on VAIO keyboards, and causes a lot of keyboard craziness. (My problem seems to be CTRL key stuck).  Theory is that FN+NumLk clears it. (Various people report SHIFT+NumLK, CTRL+NumLk, ...).    This is *such* a good use of my time... just can't wait for my next keyboard glitch :-{

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to recover from the keyboard being stuck without losing everything:

1. Use <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> (if it still works, or you can use the mouse and
   the start menu) to get to the logout/change user menu
2. Change user *to yourself*

This resets the keyboard, while retaining your the running programs.  You don't lose anything except your temper.

This is not a cure to that prevents the keyboard from sticking, so I'm not marking this as the accepted answer.